# open ssl: Verify return code: 2 (unable to get issuer certificate)

Tags: certificates, openssl

I have 3 certificates:

- root_ca.pem (self signed cert CA)
- issuing_ca.pem (Intermediate CA signed by root ca)
- user.pem (user cert signed by intermediate ca)

If I try to validate the chain with openssl

`openssl verify -verbose -CAfile <(cat issuing_ca.pem root_ca.pem) user.pem`

I get:

```
user.pem: CN = My Intermediate CA, ST = Virginia, C = US, O = "Corp.", OU = TEST
error 2 at 1 depth lookup:unable to get issuer certificate
```

I have verified all the cert one by one with

`openssl x509 -in xxx.pem -text`

And they all match (each cert is correctly signed by the parent).

How can I debug what is the issue?

EDIT:
I'll leave the post even though the issue was because the issuing_ca was not actually been signed by the provided root_ca..
(For the record I didn't create these certs myself I have just been provided with them and was certified that issuing_ca was signed by the provided root_ca)

Comment: (0) is it `issuing_ca.pem` or `.pen`? (1) Does intermediate have AuthorityKeyID (AKI) and if so does it correctly match root? (2) Does root have BasicConstraints and if so does it have CA:TRUE? (3) Does root have Key Usage and if so does it have Certificate Sign? (4) If you have 1.1.0 up, try each step separately: `verify -CAfile imed -partial_chain user` and `verify -CAfile root imed`

Comment: Yep, I saw one of your comment (specially the keyUsage one) in an other SO post and had already checked all these stuff.
`verify -CAfile root imed` was what convinced me something that something was not right with the root

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a technical error